# How can I acquire chlorophyte armour?

Tags: terraria

How can find or make chlorophyte armour in Terraria on PC?

Comment: If you have a Drax, then you could farm your own chlorophyte farm, because it's like corruption, it grows! Build a 5X5 mud block square, dig out the middle and place one piece of chlorophyte or in the middle! So easy, you just need to have patience because it takes a while to grow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can acquire chlorophyte armour through crafting it at a crafting station. 
The recipes for the different pieces of armour as follows -

[image: Chlorophyte armour crafting recipes]

> Chlorophyte Bars are crafted from 6 Chlorophyte Ore, an end-game Hardmode ore which can be found in the Underground Jungle, or grown in mud.

The chlorophyte bar crafting recipe -

[image: Chlorophyte bar crafting recipe]

Sourced from [Terraria Wiki on Gamepedia](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Chlorophyte_armor#Crafting).

Comment: You should probably also add how chlorophyte bars are made.

Comment: I've edited it and added how to find the ore and the recipe for the bars.

Answer (score 1):

You can find chlorophyte in the jungle biome.

You can mine chlorophyte by acquiring a drill called the Drax. It can be crafted with 18 hallowed bars, 1 soul of fright, sight, and might. (All of which are found on mechanical bosses)

After gathering the necessary amount of ore from the jungle, you can craft chlorophyte bars using a titanium/adamantine forge.

And then, after obtaining the chlorophyte bars, you can create chlorophyte armor using a mythril/orichalcum anvil.

Answer (score 0):

When you unlock hardmode and beat all mechanical bosses, cloriphyte should spawn. You can use the picaxe axe ore the drax to mine it. Smelt it in an adamantite/titanium forge to get cloriphyte bars. Go to an orichalcum/mythril anvil and now you can make your armor.